# Is it to colour normal text in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, text, colors, terminal

I am writting some script and it's output will be redirected to some text file and it will be automatically sent in mail by my mail client. I want to add colour to the content of my mail. I am using the below codes;

```
"\e[31mHello World\e[0m"

$fg_black="$(tput setaf 0)"
$fg_red="$(tput setaf 1)"
$fg_green="$(tput setaf 2)"
$fg_yellow="$(tput setaf 3)"
$fg_blue="$(tput setaf 4)"
$fg_magenta="$(tput setaf 5)"
$fg_cyan="$(tput setaf 6)"
$fg_white="$(tput setaf 7)"
$reset="$(tput sgr0)"
```

But these are not coloring my mail content.
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your email content should be using HTML to colorize the output. You have to convert your colors to this format. You could use a converter like [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) to output HTML compatible text and put it in your email.